# How can the result of 1 million transformations on a qubit be verified to be correct?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, circuit-construction

[image: Miniature schematic of the circuit. H,CZ,CZ are repeated on qubit 1.]I tried to do almost a million transformations on a qubit.
I made a three qubit circuit with equal superposition of |0> and |1> (using Hadamard gate) and on the first qubit (qubit 0), added one Hadamard gate followed by two CZ gates with control inputs as qubit 1 and qubit 1. The same pattern is repeated and tried to make  almost 0.9M transformations (gate count or depth) on the first qubit.
It simulated successfully and also I tried on the quantum hardware too. It ran successfully on the hardware too. Both give me equi-probable results for the qubits which had equal superposition of |0> and |1> after measurement.
I am wondering if you could help me with the correctness of my result. Whether the result I am getting in both cases are correct or not ? If not what is/are the reason/s for them to be incorrect ?
Miniature schematic of the circuit is added. H,CZ,CZ are repeated on qubit 0 as a long chain of gates and measurement is done at the end.
Looking forward to learn more.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Hello Arun, welcome. I didn’t quite understand your question. Can you clarify it please? A scheme of the circuit might help.

Comment: Hi Ohad, Miniature schematic of the circuit added on to the post. H,CZ,CZ are repeated on qubit 1 a lot of times. Hope this clarifies. Kindly let me know otherwise.